# Many to Many Query in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have have a many to many relationship in my database. The two end tables are BlogPost and Item and the table in the middle is ItemBlogPost.  I need to get back all of the BlogPosts related to a specific item.  In SQL I would do it like this:

```
SELECT BlogPost.*
FROM BlogPost
    JOIN ItemBlogPost ON BlogPost.ID = ItemBlogPost.BlogPost_ID
WHERE ItemBlogPost.Item_ID = @Item_ID
```

In C# I have something similar:

```
IQueryable<BlogPost> itemBlogPosts = from b in connection.BlogPosts
                                     where b.Items == item.ID 
                                     orderby b.Content.CreateDate descending
                                     select b;
```

However, the line marked b.Items doesn't give me a list of the Item properties and there is no b.ItemBlogPost to look at the intermediary table.  I also tried doing `b.Items.Contains(item)` but that also failed.  How can I make this work in LINQ to EF4?

Comment: If you have a many-to-many relationship set up, it should just be `item.BlogPosts`, no?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about this:

```
var itemBlogPosts = from i in connection.Items
                    from b in i.BlogPosts // I suppose you have a nav. property on Item
                    where i.Id == itemId
                    select b;
```

The same query can be also defined by:

```
var itemBlogPosts = connection.Items
                              .Where(i => i.Id == itemId)
                              .SelectMany(i => i.BlogPosts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you just do this:

```
var itemBlogPosts = connection.Items.Single(b => b.ID == item.ID).BlogPosts;
```

Since you are using EF it should handle the many-to-many mapping for you and you should have BlogPosts as a navigation item in your Item Object.

Comment: That whould first load an item and then execute second query to lazy load related blog posts.

Comment: if you dont' want to lazy load, you could just use the Include() option.

Answer (score 0):

If:

1. You generated a model from the database (so **not** model-first)
2. The connecting table contains exactly two foreign keys (without additional columns)
3. The foreign keys were set up in the right way

Then:

1. EF would have generated classes for you that contain so-called navigation properties on "both sides". A navigation property (collection of Items) on BlogPost and a nav.prop. (collection of BlogPosts) on Item.

This way:

1. You can traverse the object graph bidirectional. Getting all the blogposts for a specific item or the other way around getting all the items for a certain blogpost.

So when you have your specific item by hand you can just create a collection of related blogposts by doing:

```
Item item = context.Items.Include("BlogPosts").FirstOrDefault<Item>(i => i.ID = someID)
```

Now you have a specific item with the collection of blogposts filled (if any were related to this item).